# How can i get image url with proper path?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, json

```
<?php foreach ($temp as $product): ?>

<?php
    $id = $product['entity_id'];
    $img = $product['image'];
    $url = $product['url_path'];
    $small_image = $skinUrl.$product['small_image'];
    $small_img_lable = $product['small_image_label'];
    $thumbnail = $product['thumbnail'];
    $name = $product['name'];
    $price = $product['price'];
    $special_price = $product['special_price'];
    $size = $product['size'];
?>

<li class="product-grid_item product-tile">
<a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
<div class="quickview">
    <button class="button button--s button--inverted">Quick View</button>
</div>
   <picture class="pimg1">
       <source srcset="<?php echo $small_image; ?>" media="(min-width: 400px)">
       <img srcset="<?php echo $small_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $small_img_lable;?>">
  </picture>
  <picture class="pimg2">
      <source srcset="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" media="(min-width: 400px)">
      <img srcset="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $thumbnail;?>">
 </picture>
```

$temp contain product attributes.And i have all the attibute data in json file, but can't get image url. How can I get this ?

**"small_image":"/1/_/1_4_1.jpg"**,**"thumbnail":"/1/_/1_4_1.jpg"**
this are my small image and thumbnail image values in json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
$media = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$imageUrl = $media.'catalog/product/'. $product['image'];
```

Comment: Thank you @ashish Jagnani.
also i want only products that matches only current category in this listing page.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch like below.

```
$imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
$imageCacheUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(135,135);
$imageCacheUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(100,100);
$imageCacheUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(45,45);
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess this is an unfixed "bug" in Magento where `image` attribute isn't added to flat product tables.

[Fix](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/161): add  `<image>` to `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml`

To get full image URLs you can also use

```
$image = $product->getImageUrl();
$small = $product->getSmallImageUrl();
```

But this will not work ... *(another [bug](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/160))*

```
$thumb = $product->getThumbnailUrl();
```